# Cannot collect Random int stream into a List collection

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I've been looking up for a while how to "collect" an IntStream into a List thus generating a random int list, but the compiler keeps complaining. Piece of code below:

```
IntStream randIntStream = new Random().ints(1000);
List<Integer> randomInts =
randIntStream.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Error given by compiler:

> Error:(42, 49) java: method collect in interface
>   java.util.stream.IntStream cannot be applied to given types;
>
> required: java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer
>
> found: java.util.stream.Collector>   reason: cannot infer
>   type-variable(s) R
>       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: You have to box it `.boxed()`

Comment: or `ThreadLocalRandom.current()
                         .ints(1000)
                         .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you can collect an `IntStream` to a `List<Integer>`, you need to call `IntStream#boxed` to transform it into a `Stream<Integer>`:

```
IntStream randIntStream = new Random().ints(1000);
List<Integer> randomInts = randIntStream.boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```